# No refresh on Ng-repeat after a $http deletion

Tags: javascript, angularjs

After deleting an entry from my collection, values of the deleted object are gone, but the  **line (blank) remains.** (tried apply()...no success)

I have a typical CRUD ui with a view of expenses.

```
 <table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <td>Titre</td>
        <td>Date</td>
        <td>Montant</td>
        <td>Méthode de paiement</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="expense in expenses">
        <td>{{expense.title}}</td>
        <td>{{expense.date}}</td>
        <td>{{expense.amount}}</td>
        <td>{{expense.paiementMethod}}</td>
        <td><a class="btn btn-primary" ui-sref="editExpense({id:expense._id})">Editer</a></td>
        <td><a class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="deleteExpense(expense)">Supprimer</a> </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

binded to an expense Controller

```
angular.module('ExpenseCtrl', [])
.controller('ExpenseListController', function ($scope, $state, $window,Expense) {

    $scope.expenses = Expense.query();

    $scope.deleteExpense = function (expense) {
        expense.$delete(function () {
            $state.go('expenses');
        })
    }
})
```

which is feeded by an expense resource factory

```
angular.module('ExpenseService', []).factory('Expense', function($resource) {
return $resource('api/expenses/:id',{
    id:'@_id'},{
    update:{method:'PUT'}, delete:{method:'DELETE'}})
```

});

to Communicate with an Json API (mongodb and node/express in the back)

As so, i'm using ngResource & ui.router to handle states scenarios.

---

Note: If i refresh manually from the delete function, everything's ok, but is it something we **HAVE** to do ?

```
.controller('ExpenseListController', function ($scope, $state, $window,Expense) {

    $scope.expenses = Expense.query();
    $scope.deleteExpense = function (expense) {
        expense.$delete(function () {
            $scope.expenses = Expense.query();
        })
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove it from the `expenses` array on the scope somehow, be it through re-querying or just by removing it from the array upon successful server-side deletion. An `$http` request by itself does not effect the `$scope.expenses` object.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It becomes quite clear that $http (via $resource) does not affect any objects in the scope. i did add `$scope.expenses.splice($scope.expenses.indexOf(expense),1);` upon successful server-side deletion and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Yup. You could always instantiate an expense as a type of resource and have the http request modify the object all inside of the service but that's out of the question scope

Comment: Note that a $scope.expenses.remove(expense) did quite do the job. I learned that the indexBased deletion is the only one reliable in JS. Thkx again.